# Prevent Content Injection into HTTP Req Headers

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, security, http-headers

I am using [Requestly](https://app.requestly.in/) Chrome extension to intercept and modify HTTP request headers and change their original values inside my NodeJS app.

[image]
How can I prevent attack? For example, I can change Referer header and inject link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to prevent users from doing this.

You can't trust the Referer header.

Comment: Thanks Quentin. Would it be right if I pass the info inside req body (for example - link) then use it from the header?

Comment: @Klark — No. **Every** part of the request is under the control of the user.

Comment: In my case, the user can share content via email. The shared link will be sent to the email that user type. The shared link is my website URL - I don't want to allow user to change that.

Comment: So I think it should be fine if I pass it in body req?

Comment: If the email is being sent by the user from the email client, they can say whatever they want. If it is being sent from your server then it can say whatever you want. You can *test* if the URL submitted is one that belongs to your website and throw an error if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, but you can try to make the thing more difficult to do, thing a tricky way to sign the headers / datas (sha512, etc..) and add signature in the headers/cookie/datas.

Use the same function on your server to check if the value has been modified during the transport.

"But the 'hacker' can still try to inspect the client code and use the signature function to modify the values ?"

Yes, but you can transform the thing in something completely illisible:

- Make your app include a bench of useless big script which doing nothing (uglified of course)
- Divide your signature function in many (many) functions named with random char and then uglified them, put one of them inside your useless big scripts.
- ...

Nothing is trustable on client side, but you can try to discourage the hackers :D